# How do I interpret ARIMA(2,1,0) with drift

Tags: r, time-series, arima, seasonality, trend

The code that Î used to generate ARIMA summary is

```
arimafore = forecast(auto.arima(sales), h = 12)
summary(arimafore)
```

For forecasting 12 months I got the summary below:

```
Forecast method: ARIMA(2,1,0) with drift

Model Information:
Series: sales 
ARIMA(2,1,0) with drift 

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2      drift
      -0.8102  -0.4819  2774.6233
s.e.   0.1750   0.1688   682.3571

sigma^2 estimated as 62683829:  log likelihood=-248.34
AIC=504.67   AICc=506.78   BIC=509.39

Error measures:
                   ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 63.40175 7256.336 5466.688 -0.2247928 4.024713 0.1580417 -0.1562984

Forecasts:
         Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
Feb 2018       173223.9 163077.5 183370.4 157706.3 188741.6
Mar 2018       176272.6 165945.0 186600.2 160477.8 192067.3
Apr 2018       181744.1 170775.0 192713.2 164968.3 198519.9
May 2018       182201.7 169589.9 194813.4 162913.7 201489.6
Jun 2018       185553.8 172511.7 198595.9 165607.6 205500.0
Jul 2018       188977.2 175195.2 202759.2 167899.5 210054.9
Aug 2018       190947.9 176308.7 205587.0 168559.2 213336.5
Sep 2018       194061.2 178885.2 209237.1 170851.6 217270.8
Oct 2018       196948.9 181112.2 212785.5 172728.8 221168.9
Nov 2018       199468.7 182991.1 215946.3 174268.3 224669.0
Dec 2018       202395.3 185371.4 219419.1 176359.6 228430.9
Jan 2019       205169.6 187564.3 222774.9 178244.6 232094.6
```

Can you help me to interpret ARIMA(2,1,0) with drift? Is it more of a trend model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a model like this:

$$\Delta x_{t} = b + \sum_{i=1}^{m} \phi(i) * \Delta x_{t-i} + \sum_{j=0}{m} \theta(j) * \epsilon(t-j)$$

"Integrating" this model gives you the original $x_{t}$ model. As you can see here by the integration you'll give $a + b*t$ member in you closed form for $x(t)$:

$$x(t) = a + b*t + \sum_{i=1}{n+1} \phi_{new}(i) x(t-i) + \sum_{j=0}{m} \theta_{new}(j) * \epsilon(t-j)$$

Comment: Is it linear trend or a mixture of linear trend and seasonal

Comment: Not exactly. It's a DS-series model (stochastic trend) - model with an unit root in x(t) representation istead of TS-model with NO unit roots. So, your characteristic polynomial of x(t) with unit root will have a (1 - L) component, where L is a lag operator. Simpliest unit root (so, DS-series) model is a browian motion like x_{t} = x_{t} + \eps_{t} which could be rewrited as stationary model (white noise) for the first differences: \Delta x_{t} = \ept_{t}. And if we add const here (x_{t} = a + x_{t-1} + \eps_{t}), we will have model with drift. If add "a+b*t" - with drift and trend and so on.

Comment: So, the simpliest TS-series model (model with same trend) is an x_{t} = a + b* t + c* t^2 + \phi * x_{t} + \eps_{t} which has different type of determined trends for a, b, c  non-equal to the zero.

Comment: I strongly recommend you 2 books: "Time Series Analysis: Forecating and Control" by G. Box, G. Jenkins, G. Reinsel and G. Ljung  and the second one is "Introducing to Time Series and Forecasting" by P. Brockwell and R. Davis.